# Input Boxes under Startup Parameters Tab in SQL Server Properties is disabled

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm trying to configure something in my SQL Server and it demands this type of workaround wherein I need to add a startup parameter but I just can't because the text boxes are disabled.

I right click SQL Server(SQLExpress) and go to properties.But it seems like the text boxes under Startup Parameter are disabled. Any idea why this is happening is greatly appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I believe they're disabled because your SQL Server service is already running. Try stopping the service and check if you can add parameters then.

Comment: I tried stopping it but it's still running. I tried to check the properties of those item which has a 'Stopped' Status but still it's 'Startup Parameters text boxes are still disabled. So I assume that is true for SQL Server service also.